# Unable to clone winform project from git (.gitignore issue)

Tags: vb.net, git, visual-studio, winforms

I'm trying to clone a project from a remote git repo, the project is a VB.NET Winform project.

The issue is that once it's cloned i'm unable to use My.Resources as it's looks like something is missed when the project is loaded to git.

I've tryed to get the project directly by copy pasting from my colleague PC and all works fine but if using .GIT all .Designers.vb files are broken as My.Resources are not found (but if i right click the solution i'm able to see all Resources files)

Here is .gitignore of the project:

```
    ## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.
    
    # User-specific files
    *.suo
    *.user
    *.userosscache
    *.sln.docstates
    
    # User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
    *.userprefs
    
    # Build results
    [Dd]ebug/
    [Dd]ebugPublic/
    [Rr]elease/
    [Rr]eleases/
    [Xx]64/
    [Xx]86/
    [Bb]uild/
    bld/
    [Bb]in/
    [Oo]bj/
    
    # Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
    .vs/
    # Uncomment if you have tasks that create the project's static files in wwwroot
    #wwwroot/
    
    # MSTest test Results
    [Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
    [Bb]uild[Ll]og.*
    
    # NUNIT
    *.VisualState.xml
    TestResult.xml
    
    # Build Results of an ATL Project
    [Dd]ebugPS/
    [Rr]eleasePS/
    dlldata.c
    
    # DNX
    project.lock.json
    artifacts/
    
    *_i.c
    *_p.c
    *_i.h
    *.ilk
    *.meta
    *.obj
    *.pch
    *.pdb
    *.pgc
    *.pgd
    *.rsp
    *.sbr
    *.tlb
    *.tli
    *.tlh
    *.tmp
    *.tmp_proj
    *.log
    *.vspscc
    *.vssscc
    .builds
    *.pidb
    *.svclog
    *.scc
    
    # Chutzpah Test files
    _Chutzpah*
    
    # Visual C++ cache files
    ipch/
    *.aps
    *.ncb
    *.opendb
    *.opensdf
    *.sdf
    *.cachefile
    *.VC.db
    
    # Visual Studio profiler
    *.psess
    *.vsp
    *.vspx
    *.sap
    
    # TFS 2012 Local Workspace
    $tf/
    
    # Guidance Automation Toolkit
    *.gpState
    
    # ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
    _ReSharper*/
    *.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
    *.DotSettings.user
    
    # JustCode is a .NET coding add-in
    .JustCode
    
    # TeamCity is a build add-in
    _TeamCity*
    
    # DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
    *.dotCover
    
    # NCrunch
    _NCrunch_*
    .*crunch*.local.xml
    nCrunchTemp_*
    
    # MightyMoose
    *.mm.*
    AutoTest.Net/
    
    # Web workbench (sass)
    .sass-cache/
    
    # Installshield output folder
    [Ee]xpress/
    
    # DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
    DocProject/buildhelp/
    DocProject/Help/*.HxT
    DocProject/Help/*.HxC
    DocProject/Help/*.hhc
    DocProject/Help/*.hhk
    DocProject/Help/*.hhp
    DocProject/Help/Html2
    DocProject/Help/html
    
    # Click-Once directory
    publish/
    
    # Publish Web Output
    *.[Pp]ublish.xml
    *.azurePubxml
    
    # TODO: Un-comment the next line if you do not want to checkin
    # your web deploy settings because they may include unencrypted
    # passwords
    #*.pubxml
    *.publishproj
    
    # NuGet Packages
    *.nupkg
    # The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
    **/packages/*
    # except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
    !**/packages/build/
    # Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
    #!**/packages/repositories.config
    # NuGet v3's project.json files produces more ignoreable files
    *.nuget.props
    *.nuget.targets
    
    # Microsoft Azure Build Output
    csx/
    *.build.csdef
    
    # Microsoft Azure Emulator
    ecf/
    rcf/
    
    # Windows Store app package directory
    AppPackages/
    BundleArtifacts/
    
    # Visual Studio cache files
    # files ending in .cache can be ignored
    *.[Cc]ache
    # but keep track of directories ending in .cache
    !*.[Cc]ache/
    
    # Others
    ClientBin/
    [Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
    ~$*
    *~
    *.dbmdl
    *.dbproj.schemaview
    *.pfx
    *.publishsettings
    node_modules/
    orleans.codegen.cs
    
    # RIA/Silverlight projects
    Generated_Code/
    
    # Backup & report files from converting an old project file
    # to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
    # because we have git ;-)
    _UpgradeReport_Files/
    Backup*/
    UpgradeLog*.XML
    UpgradeLog*.htm
    
    # SQL Server files
    *.mdf
    *.ldf
    
    # Business Intelligence projects
    *.rdl.data
    *.bim.layout
    *.bim_*.settings
    
    # Microsoft Fakes
    FakesAssemblies/
    
    # GhostDoc plugin setting file
    *.GhostDoc.xml
    
    # Node.js Tools for Visual Studio
    .ntvs_analysis.dat
    
    # Visual Studio 6 build log
    *.plg

# Visual Studio 6 workspace options file
*.opt

# Visual Studio LightSwitch build output
**/*.HTMLClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/ModelManifest.xml
**/*.Server/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.Server/ModelManifest.xml
_Pvt_Extensions

# LightSwitch generated files
GeneratedArtifacts/
ModelManifest.xml

# Paket dependency manager
.paket/paket.exe

# FAKE - F# Make
.fake/
```

**UPDATE:**

By commenting

```
#[Dd]ebug/
#[Rr]elease/
#[Xx]64/
#[Xx]86/
#[Bb]uild/
#[Bb]in/
#[Oo]bj/
```

I solved the issue with designer which was not founding the My.Resources